How to find mobile number is in real world existing using Twilio without country code
I am having an input field for mobile number which uses regex to validate number and on share it share some document to that number now my query is that i had verified that sometimes i receive message status response and Sent and sometimes delivered now my ultimate query is that i want to make sure that the number entered by user before form submitting is a real number i had tried to use this https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/v1-api/validation-and-formatting    it uses country code and mobile number but issue is i ma not passing country code from frontend angular i had gone through couple of articles but i didnt found a way to verify my number without country code i am using Angular in frontend and .Net core 8 in backend
I have an input field in my application for mobile numbers. This field uses a regular expression (regex) to validate the number. When a user shares a document, it is sent to this number. I’ve noticed that sometimes the message status response is ‘Sent’, and other times it’s ‘Delivered’.
My main concern is to ensure that the number entered by the user is a valid number before the form is submitted. I’ve tried using the Twilio Lookup API for validation and formatting, which requires both the country code and mobile number. However, the issue is that I’m not passing the country code from the frontend, which is built with Angular.
I’ve read several articles, but I haven’t found a way to verify the number without the country code. For the backend, I’m using .NET Core 8. I’m looking for a solution to this problem.

Doesn't sending the message require that you have the number in E.164 format to begin with ...? If you do, then you can use the Lookup API without specifying countryCode.
